# How to overload some Groovy Type conversion for avoiding try/catch of NumberFormatException?

Tags: grails, groovy, type-conversion

I am sick of encapsuling each call of `asType` with `try/catch` block like :

```
def b = ""
def c 
try {
    c = b as Integer
}
catch (NumberFormatException) {
    c = null
}
println c
```

instead I would like to write in my code the following:

```
def b = ""
def c = b as Integer
```

and if `b` is not well-formatted, then I want to have `null` be assigned to `c`

So how can I overload this default behavior for the `asType` operator ?

Is it risky if I do it for my entire Grails application? Or is the best solution to simply create a method of my own  (like `asTypeSafe`) and call it ? Do Groovy/Grails have some configuration tweaks regarding Groovy Type conversion?

**EDIT** (for people interested in the implemented answer)
Based on the accepted answer, I have added the following code to my bootstrap.groovy file and it works perfectly.

```
String.metaClass.asTypeSafe = {Class c ->
    try {
        delegate.asType(c)
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return null
    }
}
```

and I call it as below:

```
def myNum = myStr.asTypeSafe(Integer)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the default behavior by providing a new asType implementation.  Make sure you save the old one, and call it for other classes you don't want to handle yourself.  Example:

```
oldAsType = String.metaClass.getMetaMethod("asType", [Class] as Class[])
String.metaClass.asType = { Class c ->
    if (c == Integer) { 
        delegate.isInteger() ? delegate.toInteger() : null
    } else {
        oldAsType.invoke(delegate, c)
    }
}
```

As for whether this is a good idea, just remember that a lot of objects will be be using Strings and it's quite possible they call this conversion and rely on the exception being thrown.  You're messing with things at quite a low level.

Grails domain objects will do a lot of the heavy lifting of type conversion if you pass in a params object from a controller, but I don't think it has any kind of global tweaks for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thx ! This is exactly what I needed. I might indeed add a new method to String class (like "asTypeSafe") instead of overriding asType per your suggestion. Also, where do you write and call this kind of code in a Grails application? In bootstap?

Answer (score 2):

For those of you using Grails 1.2 we now have this option when dealing with params, and I believe all GrailsParameterMaps.

```
def someInt = params.int("myInt")
```

See: http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes#Convenient%2C%20null%20safe%20converters%20in%20params%20and%20tag%20attributes